# I have error with create-react-native-app

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to create a new project with react-native using create-react-native-app myApp but instead, I get an error like this:

```
C:\Users\Septyan Rully Ekel P\Desktop>create-react-native-app myApp
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                             │
│   There is a new version of expo-cli available (3.1.2).     │
│   You are currently using expo-cli 3.0.6                    │
│   Run `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version   │
│                                                             │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
? Choose a template: expo-template-blank
√ Please enter a few initial configuration values.
  Read more: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/ · 100% completed
Extracting project files...
Customizing project...
Installing dependencies...
npm WARN deprecated deep-assign@3.0.0: Check out `lodash.merge` or `merge-options` instead.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ls":"^7.0.0","@babel/'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Septyan Rully Ekel P\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-27T03_01_42_460Z-debug.log
npm exited with non-zero code: 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm cache clean --force` and try to create the project again